# Backup bare repository did not save the child repository

Tags: git

I had a git repo (ChildRepo) within a git repo (ParentRepo).

I thought backup of ParentRepo (In a separate location, as bare repository) also keep the ChildRepo (at least the files).

Somehow, my ParentRepo got destroyed so I restored the ParentRepo from the backup bare repository. But there the ChildRepo directory is empty.

Is there anything I can do about it.

How can I get the work back?

Comment: There is no parent/child relationship between git repositories. And it is impossible under normal circumstances to keep a git repo within a git repo. Please explain how it was possible for you to have a git repo within a git repo.

Comment: You can have submodules, but I suspect that's not the case here. What happens with you do `git log`?

Comment: @matt I cloned another git repo (child) within my repo (parent) then edited the files of child. Then in parent repo I just add and commit. I did not notice that it is not keeping track of the child repo. it is just like someone has .ignored the contents of the child directory.

Comment: @Neil I do not know what to say here. There is nothing in the log. If somehow there is something in the `reflog` or somewhere then it would be helpful. I just forgot to commit changes in the child and that day the parent was lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cloned another git repo (child) within my repo (parent) then edited the files of child. Then in parent repo I just add and commit

I think you are describing something like this:

```
repo1/
  .git
  file1.txt
  repo2/
    .git
    file2.txt
```

Here, I have cloned *repo2* on the *inside* of the working tree for *repo1*.

That is an illegal configuration. Git does not complain when you clone like that, but it doesn't subsequently behave in a "normal" way either.

In particular, suppose we now edit *file1.txt* and *file2.txt*, and suppose our Terminal is in *repo1*. If we say

```
git add .
```

... then *file1.txt* will be added to the index, but *file2.txt* will not. This is because Git sees that there is another Git repo in *repo2* and keeps its hands off. It is expecting that you will manage the files inside *repo2* in some other way (such as by setting up a submodule).

Thus, if all you ever did was to say `git add .` and you never *explicitly* added any of the files inside *repo2*, then no commit that you pushed ever contained any information about those files.

> I did not notice that it is not keeping track of the child repo. it is just like someone has .ignored the contents of the child directory.

Yes, that is exactly what it is like. By default, in this illegal repo-within-a-repo situation, Git does not track any of the files inside *repo2* unless you tell it to.

<sub>I must repeat here also the comment I made earlier: you keep saying "child" and "parent" but there is *no such thing as a child repo*. That seems to be something you just assumed in your mind.</sub>

---

So, given all of that, if it is really true that there is no *other* backup of these files — if you have, for example, no separate backup drive that has been maintaining a history of your entire hard drive, local or cloud-based — then any files inside *repo2* that you did not *explicitly* add to the index of *repo1* and commit and push, being unknown to Git, are indeed completely lost.

The bare repo doesn't have them because they were never included in any commit. And if you have no *other* backup, then if the entire complex of *repo1* and all its contents at any depth is truly destroyed, then the contents of *repo2,* at least in the state you remember them, are lost forever.